# Conditional formatting, len, cell color

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I have five cells (B4, C4, D4, E4 and F4). The cells are red when they're empty, and turn green when you type a X in them. For this I use conditional formatting rules (empty cell=red, and "=len(B4)>0" turns them green).
The thing is - I'd like all of the five cells to turn green if two or more of them contain a X.

Is this possible, and if it is - how do I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following custom formula to make the cells turn green when there are 2 or more X's present:

```
=countif($B$4:$F$4,"X")>=2
```

or if you want them to turn green if at least 2 of them are non-blank:

```
=countif($B$4:$F$4,"<>")>=2
```

which means count cells which are not blank.

The dollar signs mean that the rule applies to all five cells and does not change as you move across from B4 to F4.